# Preceding and Following - Processing Instructions - XSLT 2

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

1. I am trying to match all the `<row>` elements which have certain processing instruction as preceding and the following sibling (`<?changetrack remove_begin?>` and `<?changetrack remove_end?>` )
2. If match found, search for `max(entry@morerows)` attribute and add equivalent empty rows.
3. Please see my XSLT, I need to put this logic (dummy row creation) in `<xsl:template match="row">`, so I don't have to modify existing code for @format.

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <table format="wide">
       <tgroup>
          <thead>
             <row>
                <entry>lorem ipsumrow entry</entry>
                <entry>lorem ipsumrow entry</entry>
                <entry>lorem ipsumrow entry</entry>
                <entry>lorem ipsumrow entry</entry>
                <entry>lorem ipsumrow entry</entry>
                <entry>lorem ipsumrow entry</entry>
                <entry>lorem ipsumrow entry</entry>
                <entry>lorem ipsumrow entry</entry>
             </row>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
             <?changetrack remove_begin?>
             <row>
                <entry>first row entryrow entry</entry>
                <entry>firstrow entry</entry>
                <entry>firstrow entry</entry>
                <entry morerows="3">first row entry</entry>
                <entry>firstrow entry</entry>
                <entry>firstrow entry</entry>
                <entry>firstrow entry</entry>
                <entry>firstrow entry</entry>
             </row>
             <?changetrack remove_end?>
             <?changetrack insert_begin?>
             <row>
                <entry>secondrow entry</entry>
                <entry>secondrow entry</entry>
                <entry>secondrow entry</entry>
                <entry morerows="2">secondrow entry</entry>
                <entry>secondrow entry</entry>
                <entry>secondrow entry</entry>
                <entry>secondrow entry</entry>
                <entry>secondrow entry</entry>
             </row>
             <?changetrack insert_end?>
             <row>
                <entry>Thirdrow entry</entry>
                <entry>Thirdrow entry</entry>
                <entry>Thirdrow entry</entry>
                <entry>Thirdrow entry</entry>
                <entry>Thirdrow entry</entry>
                <entry>Thirdrow entry</entry>
                <entry>Thirdrow entry</entry>
                <entry>Thirdrow entry</entry>
             </row>
             <?changetrack remove_begin?>
             <row>
                <entry>Forthrow entry</entry>
                <entry>Forthrow entry</entry>
                <entry>Forthrow entry</entry>
                <entry>Forthrow entry</entry>
                <entry>Forthrow entry</entry>
                <entry>Forthrow entry</entry>
                <entry>Forthrow entry</entry>
                <entry>Forthrow entry</entry>
             </row>
             <?changetrack remove_end?>            
             <row>
                <entry>fifthrow entry</entry>
                <entry>fifthrow entry</entry>
                <entry>fifthrow entry</entry>
                <entry>fifthrow entry</entry>
                <entry>fifthrow entry</entry>
                <entry>fifthrow entry</entry>
                <entry>fifthrow entry</entry>
                <entry>fifthrow entry</entry>
             </row>            
             <row>
                <entry>sixthrow entry</entry>
                <entry>sixthrow entry</entry>
                <entry>sixthrow entry</entry>
                <entry>sixthrow entry</entry>
                <entry>sixthrow entry</entry>
                <entry>sixthrow entry</entry>
                <entry>sixthrow entry</entry>
                <entry>sixthrow entry</entry>
             </row>
          </tbody>
       </tgroup>
    </table>
```

Expected Output:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table format="wide">
    <tgroup>
        <thead>
            <forow>
                <entry format="wide">lorem ipsumforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">lorem ipsumforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">lorem ipsumforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">lorem ipsumforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">lorem ipsumforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">lorem ipsumforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">lorem ipsumforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">lorem ipsumforow entry</entry>
            </forow>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?changetrack remove_begin?>
            <forow>
                <entry format="wide">first forow entryforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">firstforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">firstforow entry</entry>
                <entry moreforows="3">first forow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">firstforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">firstforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">firstforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">firstforow entry</entry>
            </forow>
            <forow>
                <entry format="wide">Dummy forow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Dummy forow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Dummy forow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Dummy forow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Dummy forow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Dummy forow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Dummy forow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Dummy forow entry</entry>
            </forow>
            <forow>
                <entry format="wide">Dummy forow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Dummy forow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Dummy forow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Dummy forow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Dummy forow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Dummy forow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Dummy forow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Dummy forow entry</entry>
            </forow>
            <forow>
                <entry format="wide">Dummy forow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Dummy forow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Dummy forow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Dummy forow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Dummy forow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Dummy forow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Dummy forow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Dummy forow entry</entry>
            </forow>
            <?changetrack remove_end?>
            <?changetrack insert_begin?>
            <forow>
                <entry format="wide">secondforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">secondforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">secondforow entry</entry>
                <entry moreforows="2">secondforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">secondforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">secondforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">secondforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">secondforow entry</entry>
            </forow>
            <?changetrack insert_end?>
            <forow>
                <entry format="wide">Thirdforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Thirdforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Thirdforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Thirdforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Thirdforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Thirdforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Thirdforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Thirdforow entry</entry>
            </forow>
            <?changetrack remove_begin?>
            <forow>
                <entry format="wide">Forthforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Forthforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Forthforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Forthforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Forthforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Forthforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Forthforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">Forthforow entry</entry>
            </forow>
            <?changetrack remove_end?>
            <forow>
                <entry format="wide">fifthforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">fifthforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">fifthforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">fifthforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">fifthforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">fifthforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">fifthforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">fifthforow entry</entry>
            </forow>
            <forow>
                <entry format="wide">sixthforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">sixthforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">sixthforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">sixthforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">sixthforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">sixthforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">sixthforow entry</entry>
                <entry format="wide">sixthforow entry</entry>
            </forow>
        </tbody>
    </tgroup>
</table>
```

My XSLT: It does not match the PIs

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="row">
        <xsl:variable name="format" select="ancestor::table/@format"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$format = 'wide'">
                <forow format="wide">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </forow>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$format = 'compact'">
                <forow format="compact">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </forow>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <forow>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </forow>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:if
            test="preceding-sibling::processing-instruction('changetrack')[contains(., 'remove_begin')][1] and following-sibling::processing-instruction('changetrack')[contains(., 'remove_end')][1]">
            <xsl:variable name="morerows" select="max(entry/@morerows)"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$morerows">
                <row>
                    <entry>Dummay row entry</entry>
                    <entry>Dummay row entry</entry>
                    <entry>Dummay row entry</entry>
                    <entry>Dummay row entry</entry>
                    <entry>Dummay row entry</entry>
                    <entry>Dummay row entry</entry>
                    <entry>Dummay row entry</entry>
                    <entry>Dummay row entry</entry>
                </row>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So why do you need that code for the ancestor `table` inside the template matching `row`? And if that code is necessary and already used and seems to create `forow` result elements, why are there none of them in the desired output? That doesn't make much sense to me. It seems you should write a template matching `<xsl:template match="table"><forow><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></forow></xsl:template>`. As for the XPath check for your pis, if you strip space you can check e.g. `<xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::processing-instruction('changetrack')[...]">`

Comment: sorry, I have fixed the output xml. Please see. I also tired the xpath 'preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::processing-instruction('changetrack')[contains(., 'remove_begin')]]' dint work, am I missing something in this xpath? How to strip space for particular PIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issues in your XSLT. Firstly, this expression...

```
preceding-sibling::processing-instruction('changetrack')[contains(., 'remove_begin')][1]
```

This expression is getting the first preceding "changetrack" processing that contains "remove_begin", but that might not be the immediately preceding sibling. It could be way back in the XML

The expression you want is this (with a similar one for following-sibling)

```
 preceding-sibling::node()[normalize-space()][1][self::processing-instruction('changetrack')][contains(., 'remove_begin')]
```

(You could remove the `normalize-space()` check if your XSLT did `xsl:strip-space`)

Secondly, the `<xsl:for-each select="$morerows">` is only going to iterate once, because `$morerows` only contains a single atomic type (the value of this is not being used, just the fact there is one of them).

What you need to do is this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="1 to xs:int($morerows)">
```

Where `xs` is declared as "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <xsl:variable name="format" select="ancestor::table/@format"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$format = 'wide'">
                <forow format="wide">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </forow>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$format = 'compact'">
                <forow format="compact">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </forow>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <forow>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </forow>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:if
            test="preceding-sibling::node()[normalize-space()][1][self::processing-instruction('changetrack')][contains(., 'remove_begin')] and following-sibling::node()[normalize-space()][1][self::processing-instruction('changetrack')][contains(., 'remove_end')]">
            <xsl:variable name="morerows" select="max(entry/@morerows)"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="1 to xs:int($morerows)">
                <row>
                    <entry>Dummay row entry</entry>
                    <entry>Dummay row entry</entry>
                    <entry>Dummay row entry</entry>
                    <entry>Dummay row entry</entry>
                    <entry>Dummay row entry</entry>
                    <entry>Dummay row entry</entry>
                    <entry>Dummay row entry</entry>
                    <entry>Dummay row entry</entry>
                </row>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```